# Unable to get relation attribute in Django, many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

`models.py:`

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm able to filter `books` by the `author` relation:

```
>>> Book.objects.filter(author__name__contains="Fyodor")
<QuerySet [<Book: Crime and Punishment>, <Book: The Brothers Karamazov>]>
```

However, I'm unable to get the **book's author**:

```
>>> all_books = Book.objects.all()
>>> all_books[0].author
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7fdf068a2b20>
>>> all_books[0].author.name
>>>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ManyToMany` relation between books and authors, so each book will have many authors. Hence `book.author` gives you a queryset of authors.

Thus you need to do something like this:

```py
# get a single book:
book = Book.objects.get(id=<the-book-id>)

# get all the authors of a book:
authors = book.author.all()

# get the first author of the book:
first_author = authors.first()
name = first_author.name
```